# Expected ; before ) token error in C

Tags: c, compilation, printf, token, negative-number

I'm trying to figure out a homework assignment in C. I'm supposed to have the user enter integers until they enter a negative number. At that point the program needs to stop inputting and proceed to output the sum, number of tries before a negative number is entered, and the mean.

I can't seem to find any errors in my code (although I'm sure there is), but when I try to compile I get multiple errors on my output `printf` statements that say both `expected ';' before ')' token` and `expected statement before ')' token`. I must be blind. Please enlighten me.

Here's all my code thus far:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i=0,sum=0,tries=0;
    int mean=sum/tries;
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a number %i. When finished, enter "
            "a negative number. \n",i);
        scanf("%i",&i); 
        sum+=i;
        tries++;
    }
    while(i>=-1);

    if((sum<=0) && (i<=-1))
    {
        printf("No valid numbers were entered. Try again. ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sum is %i\n"),sum);
        printf("%i tries \n"),tries);
        printf("Mean is %i \n"),mean);

    }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler tells you what line the error is on. Look at that line. The problem is obvious

Comment: Also, even if the code compiles, it would crash at runtime on this line: `int mean=sum/tries;` because `tries` is still 0 at that time. You need to calculate the `mean` *after* the loop exists, when `tries` is >= 1.

Comment: It's because the C++ standards committee decided on their latest meeting to insert winking smileys at random places in the C++ grammar so as to make the developer's work less boring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many parentheses

```
printf("Sum is %i\n"),sum);
printf("%i tries \n"),tries);
printf("Mean is %i \n"),mean);
```

Should be

```
        printf("Sum is %i\n",sum);
        printf("%i tries \n",tries);
        printf("Mean is %i \n",mean);
```

Full code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i=0,sum=0,tries=0;
    int mean=sum/tries;
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a number %i. When finished, enter "
            "a negative number. \n",i);
        scanf("%i",&i); 
        sum+=i;
        tries++;
    }
    while(i>=-1);

    if((sum<=0) && (i<=-1))
    {
        printf("No valid numbers were entered. Try again. ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sum is %i\n",sum);
        printf("%i tries \n",tries);
        printf("Mean is %i \n",mean);

    }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: These are not called scopes, these are just parentheses.

Comment: @nneonneo Sorry, it's my bad English(sometimes), thank you, I edited answer already.

Answer (score 1):

- You forgot the `include` line (`#include <stdio.h>`).
- And miss type **close parenthesis** in the print lines, should be `printf("Sum is %i\n", sum);` and not `printf("Sum is %i\n"),sum);` should also give some error similar to the posted.

This would be the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, sum = 0, tries = 0;
    int mean = sum / tries;
    do {
        printf("Please enter a number %i. When finished, enter "
               "a negative number. \n",
               i);
        scanf("%i", &i);
        sum += i;
        tries++;
    } while (i >= -1);

    if ((sum <= 0) && (i <= -1)) {
        printf("No valid numbers were entered. Try again. ");
    } else {
        printf("Sum is %i\n", sum);
        printf("%i tries \n", tries);
        printf("Mean is %i \n", mean);
    }

    return 0;
}
```